# Firebase Unity Get Data too Slow

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

i've a problem about using firebase on unity.

My json like this

```
"-MOGcdnpalVOmnxvO8ma" : {
  "imdbID" : "tt12571792",
  "imdb_moviename" : "A Queen Is Born",
  "like" : 0,
  "myDbID" : 39,
  "poster" : "N/A",
  "title" : "A Queen Is Born",
  "type" : "series",
  "unlike" : 0,
  "year" : "2020–"
},
```

And Rules for this json

```
{
  "rules": {
      "Movie": {
        ".read": true,  
            ".write": true,  
          ".indexOn": ["like"]
    }
  }
}
```

There are 4k records on firebase.
i call this method from unity but result comes in 2 minutes.

```
public GetMovieList() { 
    if (movieDatabase==null){
            movieDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("Movie");
    }
    List<Movie> movies = new List<Movie>();

    movieDatabase.OrderByChild("like").LimitToLast(10).GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            Debug.Log(" Task Fail");
            
        }

        if (task.IsCompleted) {
            Debug.Log("Task OK");
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
            foreach (DataSnapshot movierec in snapshot.Children)
            {
                Movie m = MovieParse(snapshot, movierec);
                movies.Add(m);
            }
        }
    });     
}
```

Comment: There is nothing in the API that can affect that performance. But if this is the first time you're interacting with the database, you may be looking at the time it takes to establish the initial connection. Does the data load (much) faster when you try it again?

Comment: it's working normal now. i think, First interacting was slow as you said. Thnx a lot for helping

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in the API that can affect that performance.

But if this is the first time you're interacting with the database, you may be looking at the time it takes to establish the initial connection. If that is the case, subsequent loads should be a lot faster.

Either way, it might be worth to check the connection from your system to the database (typically `https://<yourprojectname>.firbaseio.com/`) with a tool like `tracert`.